# How do cat & redirect result in different runtimes for the same command?

Tags: performance, unix, sqlite

I'm running into a case where the use of

```
cat file | executable
```

and

```
executable < file
```

result in drastically different runtimes. Specifically, I have a query which runs in 10-20 seconds using SQLite Expert or from inside command line sqlite3. I save this executable to a file and run

```
sqlite3 database.sqlite < file
```

This takes 10 - 20 seconds to run

```
cat file | sqlite3 database.sqlite3
```

Takes well over 15 minutes to run.

The databases are identical, same machine, same sql script, only the manner in which sqlite3 recieves its instruction differs. Why is it the case that I'm seeing extremely different behavior.

Note this is the case on both Unix and Windows.

Answer (score -1):

With cat, you're spawning a new process, and redirecting the output. [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) describes this very well. 
By providing the file on stdin by expansion, you're just giving an argument to the sqllite3 tool.

Comment: UUoC is a valid concern, but it doesn't account for the difference between 20 seconds and 15 minutes of runtime.

Comment: `<` is not an argument.